# Approximating $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-c^{-1})^x$

Tags: probability, limits, approximation

I have encountered the following approximation:

given that $c\le x$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1-c^{-1})^x \approx (1-x^{-1})^{x\frac{c}{x}} \approx e^{-\frac{c}{x}}$.

Can anyone explain the derivation of this approximation.

---

Edit: Here are some context:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't write "$f(x)\approx g(x)$ for large $x>0$" as $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=g(x)$ for non-constant $g$, since by definition if a limit exists it's a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ for $x$ close to $0$ you could reason that
$$(1-c^{-1})^x = e^{x \ln (1 - \frac 1c)} \approx e^{-\frac cx}$$ provided that $1/c$ is close to $0$, that is, $c$ large.

Comment: Would $\ln(1+x) \approx x$ if $x \to \infty$?

Comment: No, but your context requires $x$ small.

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing. In my context x is approaching infinity

Comment: As $c \to \infty$, $c^{-1} \to$...

Comment: c is not approaching infinity, x does. c is constant. c is equivalent to K in the image below my question.

Comment: That is correct. If $K$ is very large then $K^{-1}$ is very close to $0$.